# Javafx select multiple rows

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I'm trying to select multiple rows in JavaFX but I don't want to use keyboard (i.e. SHIFT key) for that. It should be selected after I click on it and when I click on another column it should be selected as well.

I checked some other answers here but I couldn't find something short and handy. Is there a shorter way to do it?

```
@FXML 
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MainFrameControl.class);

public TableView<Box> boxTable;
protected final ObservableList<Box> boxData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

Service service = new ServiceImpl();
private Stage mainStage;

public MainFrameControl(Stage mainStage) {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MainFrame.fxml"));
    fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
    fxmlLoader.setController(this);
    this.mainStage = mainStage;

    Stage stage = new Stage();
    try {
        fxmlLoader.load();  
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    }
    ArrayList<Box> list = service.findAllBoxen();

    TableColumn<Box, String> boxnameColumn = (TableColumn<Box, String>) boxTable.getColumns().get(0);
    boxnameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Box, String>("boxName"));

    TableColumn<Box, String> sizeColumn = (TableColumn<Box, String>) boxTable.getColumns().get(1);
    sizeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Box, String>("size"));
    
    TableColumn<Box, String> windowColumn = (TableColumn<Box, String>) boxTable.getColumns().get(2);
    windowColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Box, String>("window"));
    
    TableColumn<Box, String> costColumn = (TableColumn<Box, String>) boxTable.getColumns().get(3);
    costColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Box, String>("cost"));

    TableColumn<Box, String> locationColumn = (TableColumn<Box, String>) boxTable.getColumns().get(4);
    locationColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Box, String>("location"));

    TableColumn<Box, Boolean> beddingColumn = (TableColumn<Box, Boolean>) boxTable.getColumns().get(5);
    beddingColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Box, Boolean>("bedding"));
    
    boxTable.setItems(boxData);
```

Comment: I would add a multi-select button like android.  Click the button the subsequent selections get added (or maybe removed after another click) to a list of selections.

Comment: could you give a code example maybe in javafx?

Answer (score 44):

```
tableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(
    SelectionMode.MULTIPLE
);
```

Comment: i tried that but it doesnt work..i added after boxTable.setItems(boxData); in my code ..do i do it wrong or ?

Comment: You have two tables in hour code (tableView and boxTable), that doesn't look right, so you have other issues than multiple selection.

Comment: that was writing mistake..it doesnt make any problem i corrected it

Comment: Please correct all problems so that somebody could run your code.  Currently boxTable.setItems would give a NullPointerException because you never create a boxTable.

Comment: @jewelsea , after doing what u suggested we still need to select multiple rows with keyboard (Ctrl+Click), is there a way do it with only mouse click?

Answer (score 5):

A custom [RowFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#setRowFactory-javafx.util.Callback-) is a good solution for this problem:

```
boxTable.setRowFactory(new Callback<TableView<Box>, TableRow<Box>>() {
    @Override
    public TableRow<Box> call(TableView<Box> tableView2)
    {
        final TableRow<Box> row = new TableRow<>();

        row.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event)
            {
                final int index = row.getIndex();

                if (index >= 0 && index < boxTable.getItems().size())
                {
                    if(boxTable.getSelectionModel().isSelected(index))
                        boxTable.getSelectionModel().clearSelection(index);
                    else
                        boxTable.getSelectionModel().select(index);

                    event.consume();
                }
            }
        });
        return row;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This is just a basic idea of what you may be looking for.  Could use a bit of improvement but I'm unclear on the intended use.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TablePosition;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ObservableList<LineItem> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        items.addAll(new LineItem("hello",123.45),
                     new LineItem("paid in full",0.01),
                     new LineItem("paid",0.01),
                     new LineItem("due",0.01),
                     new LineItem("paid",0.01));

        ObservableList<LineItem> filteredItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList(items);
        TableView<LineItem> tableView = new TableView<>(filteredItems);
        ObservableList<TablePosition> selectedCells = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        Button multi = new Button("Multi-select");
        multi.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                multi.setText((multi.getText().equals("Multi-select"))?"Single-select":"Multi-select");
                selectedCells.clear();
            }
        });

        TableColumn<LineItem,String> descCol = new TableColumn<>("desc");
        descCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("desc"));

        TableColumn<LineItem, Double> amountCol = new TableColumn<>("amount");
        amountCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("amount"));

        tableView.getColumns().addAll(descCol,amountCol);
        tableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
        tableView.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

        //maybe you want onTouchPressed here for tablet
        tableView.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                if (multi.getText().equals("Single-select")) return;
                selectedCells.add(
                    tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(
                        tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().size()-1
                    )
                );
                for (TablePosition tp : selectedCells){
                    tableView.getSelectionModel().select(tp.getRow(), tp.getTableColumn());
                }
            }
        });

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(tableView, multi);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300);

        primaryStage.setTitle("multi select table test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public class LineItem {

        private final StringProperty desc = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final DoubleProperty amount = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

        public StringProperty descProperty() {return desc;}
        public DoubleProperty amountProperty() {return amount;}

        public LineItem(String dsc, double amt) {
            desc.set(dsc); amount.set(amt);
        }
    }

}
```