# how to select multiple column in tableview

Tags: javafx, tableview

In need of building a desktop application to deal table data imported from csv files, I have been working with JavaFX few months.

Now, I have hit a problem: I can't select multi-column in a tableview. What I want to do is that in my application users can select two columns, then trigger a button to combinate them into a new column and append the new one into the tableview. But it seem that JavaFX's TableView do not support to select multi-column or even a single column. In Swing I can finish this work easily with the link [Java Swing Tutorials to Use Table](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

However, I have done by adding listeners to column headers and setting  corresponding trigger action like lighlight the selected columns and adding the selected to a recording List so that as user press the button my application could know what user selected.

But I think there must be some way nicely to meet the demand. And so what is it? Please give some useful imformation or tourials.

Comment: you can refer to @jewelsea 's  answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22582706/javafx-select-multiple-rows) and see if that helps you.

Comment: Do you mean to set `SelectionMode.MULTIPLE`？ That way could let me select multiple row but not multiple column.

Comment: so holding ctrl and clicking on the next column doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work. Well, it my stupid to make such a mistake? But in my application that way does not work. Do you have any sample? Please show me.

Comment: There's no nice way to do this in JavaFX that I am aware of. You will need to set cell selection on the table view's selection model and register listeners with the table headers that manipulate the list of selected cells. (To register a handler with the table header, use a graphic - e.g. a label - in place of text in the table column, and register handlers with the graphic.)

Comment: Yes, I had done by that way. But it would be complicated and painful to maintain with those cumstomized code for someone else later.